# Rails 4 How to redirect from from Model class to Controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to implement the following logic:
We interact with our database through normal views. Through the views the
basic CRUD operations can be performed on database objects. Whenever now a specific boolean (for any record) is set to true  i would like to pass this record to an REST API controller which then build a http string to be send to a known client.

In the model class i observe the needed value with a `after_update` callback

```
 private
    def check_boolean
        @listofusers ||= Array.new
         if self.boolean_changed?
             @listofusers.push(self)
         end    
             #redirect_to send_updates_path
             #redirect_to :controller =>'api/users',:action=>"send_updates"
      end
```

This is the route i included in my `routes.rb` to get the named helper

```
get 'send_updates', to: 'api/user#send_updates', as: :send_updates
```

But i get the following error message:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `redirect_to' for #<User:0x00000005abc778>):
```

What is the correct way to redirect to a controller action? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is impossible and against the MVC model.

When is your after_update#check_boolean method called ? During a controller action right ? There's no black wizard executing a piece of code out of nowhere.

Basically from what I understand, whenever a user uses a view to update a model instance, you want to "broadcast" an update to some HTTP clients. You should put the "broadcast code" in some separate library (which I called Broadcaster), and call this library from within your controller.

Also, you cannot execute a controller action to send your updates. Controller actions are meant to reply to a request from a particular client, not to send messages to any client. How do your clients maintain a connection with the Rails server anyways ? Rails is CRUD/RESTful and doesn't really maintain an active connection. I believe your client_list is stored inside your model, and you'll have have to use gems like Net::HTTP to broadcast those updates

app/controllers/foos_controller.rb

```
def FoosController

  def your_action_that_triggers_broadcast_to_clients
    if @your_model.update_attributes(model_params)
      if Broadcaster.broadcast_updates(@your_model)
        flash[:notice} = "Model updated and changes broadcasted"
      else
        flash[:warning] = "Model updates but changes were not broadcasted successfully"
      end 
      redirect_to @your_model, 
    else
      render 'show', alert: "Problems with validation"
  end

end
```

Your library code that broadcasts updates

```
module Broadcaster

  module_functions

  def broadcast_updates(model)
    @user_list = model.get_broadcast_list
    @user_list.each do |client|
      Net::HTTP.post_form(....)
    end

    # Return true/false on successful/unsuccessful broadcast
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

### What you're asking is an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

To retain the data integrity within your models & db, Rails keeps a strong divide between your `model` and `controller` code:

[image]

Such is the divide that some seemingly simple cross-overs, such as the `Devise` `current_user` method are actually prevented from occurring.

Thus, you have to re-think how your structure works.

--

In short, you should **keep your logic in your controller**:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def update
      @model = Model.find params[:id]
      @model = Model.update model_params
      if @model.boolean_changed?
          ## do something here
      else
          redirect_to ...
      end
   end
end
```

Any data manipulation can be kept in your model; your controller is where all your business logic should reside.

To add to this, you must remember, as per the diagram above, that Rails will not be sending data directly to your model. It goes through the *controller* first, and thus is the right place to keep your logic.

What you're doing is like trying to steer your car with the engine.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for your explanation! So generally speaking when can this callbacks be used in a proper way on the model class? As far as i understand now, a callback on a model would then trigger the following action, which is not desired since all logic should stay in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

I agree with the answerers above who mention this is a Rails anti-pattern, and suggest Rails-way solutions. Yes. Those are good, but I want to present some ideas for thought. This type of triggered-action commonly exists in operating systems via a asynchronous task loops and semaphores, or via a hardware interrupt.

**Asynchronous task loop**

Since you don't have a hardware interrupt available on a Boolean in a database, you're left with the need for an asynchronous task loop and a semaphore, maybe even a mutex to lock the semaphore if multiple users are hitting on a particular Boolean. But keeping it simple, consider a  timer-based task loop that checks the semaphore Boolean in each database.

Is this possible in a Rails web application? Is this also an anti-pattern?

This may just be a theoretical argument, but I think a timer task setup per proper MVC architecture is not an anti-pattern, it's a solution. It seems someone has written a gem for running an asynchronous (to the Rails app itself) timer task periodically [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever). I can't vouch for it, but it suggests that this solution is possible.

**Timer loop drawbacks**

- One foreseeable drawback would be if the loop is scheduled frequently and hitting each table in the database it may seriously impact performance.
- If your booleans are being flipped rapidly and constantly, then the
  timer task may not be a suitable solution
- All the unknowns (to me) about your app may make this an unsuitable solution.

**Server task**

Another idea is to create a server-side task that will essentially do the same thing, but faster and possibly with less overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into a pubsub framework to do this.  No only is it anti-pattern as others have stated, it really isn't a efficient way to send notifications to the client.

I have personally used [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/), but [Google has one](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs), as does [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/).  Rails 5 will include [ActionCable](https://github.com/rails/actioncable) which will allow this to be done natively.